# Solving the Schrödinger Equation with Fourier Transforms. A few questions

Tags: proof-explanation, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

I'm reading through a method for finding solutions to Schrödinger's equation through Fourier transforms, and I'm truly lost on the proof, hence I thought of asking for some help.

The following is from Hall's *Quantum Theory for Mathematicians*.

---

**Proposition 4.2** Suppose that $\psi_0$ is a “nice” function, for example, a Schwartz function. Let $\hat{\psi}_0$ denote the Fourier transform of $\psi_0$ and define $\psi(x, t)$ by
$$\psi(x, t) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{\psi}_0(k)e^{i(kx-\omega(k)t)},$$
where $\omega(k)$ is defined by
$$\omega(k) := \frac{k^2\hbar}{2m}.$$
Then $\psi(x, t)$ solves the free Schrödinger equation with initial condition $\psi_0$.

**Proof.** . Since the Fourier transform of a Schwartz function is a Schwartz function, $\hat{\psi}_0(k)$ will decay faster than $1/k^4$ as $k$ tends to $±∞$.

Meanwhile, by integrating the derivative of the function eikx, we obtain the estimate

$$\left|\frac{e^{ik(x+h)}-e^{ikx}}{h}\right| \le |k|.$$

**Q1:** how exactly is this bound derived?

We can then apply dominated convergence, using $|k|\hat{ψ}_0(k)$
as our dominating function, to move a derivative with respect to $x$ under the integral sign in the formula for $ψ(x, t)$. This derivative pulls down a factor of $ik$ inside the integral. The decay of $\hat{ψ}_0$ allows us to repeat this argument to move a second derivative with respect inside the integral. We can also move a derivative with respect to $t$ inside the integral, by a similar argument.

**Q2:** what does the above paragraph mean exactly?

Since $\exp{i(kx − ω(k)t)}$ satisfies the Schrödinger equation for each fixed $k$, differentiation under the integral shows that $ψ(x, t)$ satisfies the Schrödinger equation as well. The Fourier inversion formula shows that $ψ(x, 0) = ψ_0(x)$.

**Q3:** how does the Fourier inversion formula show that?

Comment: (It's Schrödinger, not Schröedinger. Sometimes it's written as Schroedinger, where oe is used as a substitute för ö, but with öe it just looks weird.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Question 1, note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left|e^{ik(x+h)}-e^{ikx}\right|&=\left|\int_x^{x+h} ike^{ikt}\,dt\right|\\\\
&\le \int_x^{x+h}\left|ike^{ikt}\right|\,dt\\\\
&\le |kh|
\end{align}$$

We will use this result to answer the next question.

---

---

For Question 2, note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi(x,t)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat \psi_0(k)e^{-i\omega(k)t}\frac{e^{ik(x+h)} -e^{ikx}}{h}\,dk\tag1
\end{align}$$

Now, inasmuch as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |k\hat \psi_0(k)|\,dk<\infty$, then the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that we can bring the limit inside the integral in $(1)$ to find that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi(x,t)&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat \psi_0(k)e^{-i\omega(k)t}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{ik(x+h)} -e^{ikx}}{h}\,dk\\\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat \psi_0(k) ik e^{i(kx-\omega(k)t)}\,dk
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Now repeating the process, we find that

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\psi(x,t)=i\hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\psi(x,t)$$

which means that $\psi(x,t)$ as given by the $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat \psi_0(k) e^{i(kx-\omega(k)t)}\,dk$ satisfies the free Schrodinger equation.

---

---

For Question 3, note that we have

$$\psi(x,0)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat \psi_0(k) e^{ikx}\,dk\tag2$$

But we know that $\hat \psi_0$ is the Fourier Transform of $\psi_0$.  The expression in $(2)$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat \psi_0$.  Hence, by the inversion theorem we see that

$$\psi(x,0)=\psi_0(x)$$

And we are done!

Comment: Hi @sam .  Pleased to see that this was useful.  Please let me know if there are any questions.